# syncing markup/word notes over dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, notes

hi i'd like to have the following functionality:

- putting a file into my dropbox (html,wordformat) - which i'm editing from my PC
- android app for acessing that file (desktop shortcut), display html/word-format + edit

any ideas?

currently i'm using a textfile which i can edit with the default android-editor, but markup would be better :)

thanks

Comment: i saw that but epistle is not at the android market anymore :(

Comment: You're right. The developer has a new, similar app now. There was also a similar question; let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Epistle has been replaced by [Draft](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mvilla.draft). That said, searching for "markdown" on the Google Play Store offers a number of possibilities. Have you tried any of them?